# Twilio pay integration with Braintree

Tags: twilio, braintree, twilio-studio

I am trying to integrate Twilio  with Braintree. Twilio pay should be included in Twilio studio. Is there any direct(without using third party tools) integration example or document is available? Any  help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio `<Pay>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/pay) requires payment partners to be built into the system. You can request a new payment partner here: https://www.twilio.com/pay/request-connector. You can't build your own connector.